# Соотношение сторон ImageView

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview

Как в макете указать размер картинки, чтобы высота соблюдала пропорции ширины? 
Любой параметр `scaleType` и `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` не работает. 
Нашел единственный выход явно указывать высоту через dp. Но такой способ не нравится.

```
<ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="32dp"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@drawable/logo"/>
```

Comment: приложите код вашего imageview пожалуйста

Comment: В ConstraintLayout есть параметр layout_constraintDimensionRatio , через который можно указать соотношение сторон виджета, в том числе и квадрат. Или писать свой класс-наследник от ImafeView. [смотреть варианты](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21437224/7566397)

Comment: @Andrew прикрепил код в ответе.

Comment: @Pempium4, код нужно в вопрос крепить а не в ответ!!!